# How to plot daily increment data from a sparse data set with interpolation in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

How can I plot time-grouped increment data in a bar graph in Grafana, but with a sparse data source that needs interpolation BEFORE calculating the increment?

My data source is an InfluxDB with a sparse time series of accumulated values (think: gas meter readings). The data points are usually a few days apart.
My goal is to create a bar graph with value increase per day. For the missing values, linear interpolation will do just fine.

I've come up with

```
SELECT spread("value") FROM "gas" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1d) fill(linear)
```

but this won't work as the `fill(linear)` command is executed AFTER the `spread(value)` command. If I use time periods much greater than my granularity of input data (e.g. time(14d)), it shows proper bars, but once I use smaller periods, the bars collapse to 0.

How can I apply the interpolation BEFORE the difference operation?

Answer (score 1):

Described situation by you is caused by fact that fill() fills data only if you do not have anything in your group by time() period in your query. If you get spread=0 then you probably have only one value in this period, so no fill() is used.
What I can suggest to you is to use subquery with lower group period time to prepare interpolation of your original signal. This is an example:

```
SELECT spread("interpolated_value") FROM (
  SELECT first("value") as "interpolated_value" from "gas" 
  WHERE $timeFilter 
  GROUP BY time(10s) fill(linear)
) 
GROUP BY time(1d) fill(none)
```

Subquery will prepare value for each 10s period (I recommend to set this value possibly as high as you can accept). If in 10s periods are values, it will pick the first one, if there is no value in this period, it will do an interpolation.
In main query there is an usage from prepared interpolated set of values to calculate spread.
All above only describes how you can get interpolated data within shorted periods. I strongly recommend to think about usability of this data. Calculating spread from lineary interpolated data may have questionable reliability.